# SharedQueue closed - RabbitMQ error message

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit, rabbitmq-exchange

I am getting SharedQueue closed error as soon as I start my application in visual studio. The error is very frequent now. As far as I know we have not made any changes to the code & this code was workign fine earlier.

I have seen many similar error post both online and on SO but I did not find any post helpful. When the exception occours it does not point to any code. Please see below error for more information:

[image]

Here is the error stack trace:

```
 at RabbitMQ.Util.SharedQueue.EnsureIsOpen()
   at RabbitMQ.Util.SharedQueue.Dequeue(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, Object& result)
   at MassTransit.Transports.RabbitMq.RabbitMqConsumer.Get(TimeSpan timeout) in d:\BuildAgent-02\work\19b3d91f8acfae7a\src\Transports\MassTransit.Transports.RabbitMq\RabbitMqConsumer.cs:line 94
```

I am not sure its relvant but I am attaching queue status as well:

[image]

Comment: Can you add the rabbitmq logs ? Try to take the logs during this error

Comment: Do the errors occur at the same time the application pool is recycled? this is a problem i have experienced in the past and was resolved by upgrading the version of the MassTransit package

Comment: @Paul: Thank you for quick reply. I do not see any other errors. What I observed is lot of messages goes into `queue_error` queue. if you see image attached in the question you will see two queues having 296 & 5847 messages.

Comment: @SharpCoder, did you find the solution to this problem? I was put this problem on my lap and having trouble to find out what the root of the problem is. Thanks

Comment: @FabioMilheiro : unfortunately I could not find the solution.

Comment: OK, @SharpCoder. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that something is disposing of an `IEndpoint` instance, which was perhaps used to send or receive a message, and that disposal is closing down the transport. This results in the receive queue being closed, without the bus being aware of it.

The only object references that should be disposed when using MassTransit is the `IServiceBus` instance when the service is exiting. Disposing of that object cleans up everything else.

Comment: This error message is not frequent & once it starts to come, it will continue to come for some time. I am still not sure where to look !!